# Css selector or Xpath approach?

Tags: html, css, xpath

I'm attempting to write a css selector for an automated test using WebDriver for the following HTML block so I can select a radio button.

```
<span data-id="c1cf48c1-fbe3-44ea-ac5c-dfe588f0ed18" class="folder">
<input id="Folders" name="Folders" type="radio" value="c1cf48c1-fbe3-44ea-ac5c-dfe588f0ed18">               Contract Folder
</span>
```

I've attempted to write an xpath expression `//*[contains(.,"Contract")]` to no avail as there are too many elements being returned, and when I try `//*[contains(.,"Contract Folder")]` nothing is being returned. Therefore Im trying css which I would prefer to use. The value attribute is dynamic so Im unable to use that as a reference.

Can someone help advise what is the best approach in this scenario?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As element IDs are not unique in OP's use case (see comments for @alecxe's answer), you can use an XPath solution, based on the text content in the `span`:

```
.//span[@class="folder"][normalize-space(.)="Contract Folder"]/input[@type="radio"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't get the `input` by `id` attribute?

```
//input[@id="Folders"]
```

Comment: or with CSS, `input#Folders`

Comment: I tried this and found there are four elements in total being returned with this xpath expression. It needs to be a more unique identifier.

Comment: @Django_Tester ok, could you show what elements are returned? Just to see the difference and what else can we check. Thanks.

Comment: @Django_Tester, element ids should be unique, if this query is returning more than one result, something is wrong! imo I would remove the id attribute from the radio button and select by child selector & attribute. i.e `span.folder > input[name="Folders"]`

Comment: @epoch Again, it's returning four elements.

Comment: @Django_Tester, assuming you can't modify the output, you will need to iterate the results. `$('span.folder > input[name="Folders"]').find(function(a) { return a.innerText.indexOf('Contract') > -1; })`, note this is semi-pseudo... (http://jsfiddle.net/KqtNz/)

Comment: `id`s should be unique... but HTML is not always that pure and clean :) I'd go with XPath in that case since testing for text content is not standard CSS. I suggest `//span[@class="folder"][normalize-space(.)="Contract Folder"]/input[@type="radio"]`

Comment: @paultrmbrth you are an xpath maniac :) You should probably post your solution as an answer.

Comment: @paultrmbrth Yes please do post your solution as answer so this can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is to easy thinking, but can't you give all your inputs the same class.

```
<input class="radioButton" ... />

input.radioButton { ... /* style */ ... }
```

Comment: Im unable to change the code as Im writing automated tests for the application. I've updated the question with this info. Sorry if it wasn't clear.